# Getting SIGABRT Just By Linking Library

Tags: qt, gcc, rocksdb

Just getting started with RocksDB. I am using QT Creator 4.7.1 with gcc 5.3.1 on Linux Mint 18.1 64 bit and have created a minimal QT Widgets program that links static librocksdb.a.

I only include some RocksDB .h files and have a simple test code function with some RocksDB calls, but do not call this test function. It compiles and links fine with no issues. Before any GUI shows up, I get a SIGABRT. I get the same result when linking with the shared library. If I remove the test function, the GUI launches as it should. I have used QT for years and have never seen a program crash just by linking a library.

Also, I built RocksDB with "sudo make install-static". The library is around 400MB. I read that this should not include debug info, but from the size it appears that it did.

Any ideas?

Comment: It compiles because it finds test function's declaration in .h, it crashes because it cannot find test function implementation which means that the library is not linked. How do you link the library?

Comment: My test function is one that I wrote that exists in MainWindow, so it is being found. The test function contains calls to RocksDB, just enough to get started. And the test function is called by a button press that never has a chance to occur because the program crashes first. My guess is that there is an initialization process happening in RocksDB, possibly by static classes, that is crashing. But I don't know. I link the library by adding it into the .pro file like I have with a hundred other libraries. Never had any issues before.

Comment: If you are on Linux, `ldd yourprocessname` to list all libraries, if your are on windows use the tool http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to list your linked libraries.